# how to remove one spacing from a string in a txt file?

Tags: java, string

lets say i has a text file.

Inside the text file has a string namely "He  is" in between the two words.

Notice that the string has 2 space.

I would like to remove one space and the desired output is "He is".

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

```
s.replaceAll("\\s\\s+", " ")
```

will replace any number of spaces more than 1, with 1 space.

Answer (score 1):

Read the whole file into a string, and then replace all double spaces by single spaces as follows.  You can read in the whole file using StreamReader.ReadToEnd().  This assumes that your file is not too large.

I thought this was a C# question, (I found it in the C# question list) and here's the C# code.

```
StreamReader streamReader=new StreamReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Read));
string str=streamReader.ReadToEnd();
string str2=str.Replace("  "," ");
```

In Java, some of the function names are not capitalized, such as replace(), and apparently, not all these classes are available.

Then just write back to the file.  You can use StreamWriter for this.

Comment: sure about that method? doesn't exist.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy:  Which method?  ReadToEnd()?  It should be there.

Comment: @Eugenio : He means `Replace` -- you want `replace`

Comment: @Hogan:  Oh... I found this on the C# questions, so I thought it was C#...  I'll change it.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy:  I see what you mean...  I thought this was a C# question.  I changed my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Eugenio - there is also no StreamReader class and no ReadToEnd method in any of the reader classes. The closest thing is ObjectInputStream.readFully().

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into memory as an array of strings, then call replace("  ", " ") for each and write the file out again. If it's too big to fit in memory, copy the file to a temp file one line at a time, doing the replace, and then delete the original file and move the temp file to where the original was.

Answer (score 1):

In java (it seems everyone is giving examples in C variants)

```
 str.replace("  "," ");
```

should work.  Case matters.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
str.replace("  ", " ");
```